# Determining the Picard group of $k[x,y]$ without using Quillen-Suslin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Define a locally invertible module over a ring $R$ as a module such that at every prime, the principal localization at some $f$ not in the prime is a free $R_f$ module.  Define the Picard group of a ring $R$ as the isomorphism classes of finite locally invertible $R$-modules.
Let $k$ be a field. The proof that I came up with showing that the Picard group of $R=k[x,y]$ is trivial is that

1. If the module $M$ is finite locally invertible then it is projective.  This is because $\mathrm{Hom}(M,-)$ is exact.
2. By Quilllen-Suslin, this means $M$ is finite free.

Thus if $M=\oplus R^n$, $M_f=\oplus R_f^n$, $n=1$ and $M \cong R$.

> Question:  It has to be possible to show the Picard group of $k[x,y]$ is trivial by hand by localizing at $\langle x \rangle$ and then using that $k(x)[y]$ is a pid, or something. How can I do this?

Comment: Picard group of any UFD is trivial.

Comment: As @Mohan points out, the Quillen-Suslin theorem is really only contentful for higher rank vector bundles. For line bundles the result is trivial. This is really something about the fact that while general primes in a ring are hard, often height $1$ primes are simpler (i.e. divisors are simpler than general cycles).

Comment: Are you saying that the splitting principle that I learned in topology fails for algebraic vector bundles?

Comment: @DeYang I don't really see how that's relevant here. Also, depending on what you mean, the answer to that question is 'no, it still holds', but that's a hard result of Serre.

Comment: I guess it is only relevant through a previous misconception of mine:  The characteristic classes of a vector bundle are nonzero iff they are nonzero when they are split over the  flag bundle.  If it were true that a vector bundle is trivial iff  the pullback to the flag manifold is trivial, then this would imply that vector bundles over $\mathbb{A}^n$ are trivial.

Comment: @DeYang: Regarding the splitting principle: in algebraic geometry you can't expect to literally split a vector bundle.  What you can do is pull it back to the relative flag bundle, over which it obtains a filtration by sub-bundles, with the associated graded pieces being line bundles.   In the topological setting you can split the extensions between the associated graded pieces, but in algebraic geometry you can't do that in general.

Comment: @tracing I think you *can* get an actual splitting after a smooth pullback. Let $F \subset E$ be an inclusion of vector bundles of ranks $s<r$, and consider the affine bundle $$P \subset \operatorname{Hom}(E,F) \qquad P_x = \{E_x \to F_x \mid (F_x \hookrightarrow E_x \to F_x) = \operatorname{id}_{F_x}\}.$$ If $f \colon P \to X$ is the projection, then $f^*\colon A^*(X) \hookrightarrow A^*(P)$ and $f^*E \cong F \oplus f^*(E/F)$. I don't know a reference for this, though.

Comment: Right.  And To get the vector(line) bundle $F$ as a subbundle of $E$, you pull back to the projectivization of the bundle $E$.  All I was saying is that  the triviality of the pullback bundle does not imply the triviality of $E$.(it is true though that all characteristic classes of $E$ would be trivial since $P(E) \to E$ is injective on cohomology.)

Comment: Apologize for my notation $P(E)$.